# json read multiply lines as new onces

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem, my app have an issue when reading more than one value, when there are two it returns zero.

Example:

I get:

male: 
{"name":"alexanderbb10","pic":"ico/nopic.png"}
{"name":"admin","pic":"ico/nopic.png"}

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://p********************************/explore.php?usr="+******************+"&what="+strUser,
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data)
    {
$('#explorediv').append('<div id="pic" data-bb-type="item" data-bb-img="' + data.pic + '" data-bb-title="' + data.name + '">' + data.name + '</div>').show('fast');

    }
    });
```

But it only shows one result.

How can i make sure it shows all results?

The server side is php

Answer (score 0):

wrapper two object in an array

```
{male: [{"name":"alexanderbb10","pic":"ico/nopic.png"}, {"name":"admin","pic":"ico/nopic.png"}]}

var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

for (var i = 0, len = result.male.length; i < len; ++i) {
  // result.male[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your is an invalid JSON:

```
male: {"name":"alexanderbb10","pic":"ico/nopic.png"} {"name":"admin","pic":"ico/nopic.png"}
```

if returned data from the ajax request is an array of object, like

```
[
    {"name":"alexanderbb10","pic":"ico/nopic.png"}
    {"name":"admin","pic":"ico/nopic.png"}
]
```

for show all the element inseide of the data you must cicle all the array element, try to change the success function like this:

```
function(data) {
    for(var k in data){
          $('#explorediv').append('<div id="pic" data-bb-type="item" data-bb-img="' + data[k].pic + '" data-bb-title="' + data.name + '">' + data[k].name + '</div>').show('fast');
    }
}
```

Comment: My server side is:

    header("Content-type: application/json");
$array['name'] = $usernick;
$array['pic'] = $durl;

echo json_encode($array);



I guess this is wrong?

Comment: your service in PHP return a single associative or an array of associative array?

Comment: insert a console log inside your callback to write in console the value of data, and tell me the data structure.
console.log(data);

Comment: Frogmouth i get more than one result normally, but i use php on server side. and with console.log(data) i get: Object {name: "sexyswe", pic: "ico/nopic.png"}

Comment: right! Object format is correct, but for not control any time if result are array of object or a single object is better if you alweys return from your php script a simple array (also if you have one elmenent) and loop this with for or .each() loop like in my exsample. If you return a single my example not work!